# R: "backfill" a table from another table (dplyr/sql)

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I am using R programming language. I have Table_1 that looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

Table_1 <- data.frame(
    
    "Col_A" = c("111", "111", "111", "112", "112", "112", "113", "113", "113", "113"),
    "Col_B" = c("AAA", "AAB", "AAC", "AAB", "ABC", "CDE", "CDE", "AAB", "AAE", "ADF")
    
)

Table_1$Col_A = as.factor(Table_1$Col_A)
Table_1$Col_B = as.factor(Table_1$Col_B)
```

I want to create a new table (Table_2) such that for "groups of the same entries in Table_1$Col_A", two columns (in Table_2) are create that record all possible combinations of values from Table_1$Col_B.

Table_2 should look something like this:

```
Table_2 <- data.frame(

"Col_C" = c("AAA", "AAA", "AAB", "AAB", "AAB", "ABC", "CDE", "CDE", "CDE", "AAB", "AAB", "AAE"),
"Col_D" = c("AAB", "AAC", "AAC", "ABC", "CDE", "CDE", "AAB", "AAE", "ADF", "AAE", "ADF","ADF")
)
```

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this? Since Table_1 is a small table, I have started manually creating Table_2 using Microsoft Excel - however, I would like to find a quicker way to solve this problem.

Could someone please tell me if it is possible to do this with the "dplyr" library or base R?

I tried something like :

```
Table_2$Col_C =  (select * distinct from Table_1$Col_B)
Table_2$Col_D = (select * from Table_2$Col_A where Table_2$Col_D = Table_1$Col_B)
```

But I don't think this is the correct way to approach this problem. Can this be done with the "reshape2" library using the melt() function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A base R approach using `combn` would be :

```
result <- do.call(rbind, by(Table_1$Col_B, Table_1$Col_A, function(x) {
                  data.frame(t(combn(x, 2)))
          }))
rownames(result) <- NULL
result

#    X1  X2
#1  AAA AAB
#2  AAA AAC
#3  AAB AAC
#4  AAB ABC
#5  AAB CDE
#6  ABC CDE
#7  CDE AAB
#8  CDE AAE
#9  CDE ADF
#10 AAB AAE
#11 AAB ADF
#12 AAE ADF
```

Not sure why you need data to be factors it is better to keep them as characters here.

```
Table_1[] <- lapply(Table_1, as.character)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Why is it better to keep them as characters?

Comment: Because here we are treating `Col_B` values differently for each `Col_A` so they'll have different levels after creating their combinations which will create issues when combining them.

Comment: Thanks - and then you can convert them to factor?

Comment: Yes, if you want them as factors you can do `result[] <- lapply(result, factor)`